# what is the pin function of relay?

Tags: relay

relay is the backwarder technology than transistor to switching or amplify.But i couldn't find the clearly symbol to understand standard 10 pins relay here:
[url](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFHeMsKA9wFRE2zI4xb3vrvIPX-25LDYWTaB9x8kEmcHz5eOtl_w)[image: picture]
could you help me to find what pin as the "gate" in transistor and does every relay are all work at opening mode in default?

Comment: Please provide a link to datasheet. I suspect that English is not your first language. You should say this on your Lan... profile page so that people make an allowance. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: please check here: http://datasheet.octopart.com/TQ2-5V-Panasonic-datasheet-16066.pdf

Comment: Add that link to the question itself!

Comment: Also, that datasheet covers **a lot** of **very different** devices, you need to specify which one exactly you're talking about

Comment: Learn to start a sentence using a capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That relay has two coils and appears to be a latching relay. The relay will remain in it's current state when power is removed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiMjR9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1 (a) A pushbutton test circuit. (b) A transistor switched circuit.*